# C# Case which include other cases

Tags: c#, switch-statement

How to execute in one case, other cases? I could just copy paste those other cases, or put it to some external function but there is so much code so I dont want to do that.

Example:

```
 switch(foo) 
 {     
    case 3:     
    {             
        //something     
    }break;          
    
    case 4:     
    {             
        //something else     
    }break;      
    
    case 5:     
    {             
        //here i want to execute case 3 and case 4     
    }break;      
}
```

I think that this was previously answered but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: If there is so much code, this is one more reason to refactor it into a method.

Comment: yeah, but if there is a way to do that, it would be great without changing the rest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I **strongly recommend changing the way you want to implement this statement**. This method is **not suitable** for modern applications and is **coupled with everything**. But if you need to implement as you asked, You can jump between cases by using **goto**.

For more information Read "[jump statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements)".

```
int a = 10;

switch (a)
{
case 0:
//Condition1:
//some actions
break;
case 1:
    goto case 0;
    //or
    goto Condition1;
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Since this is the linear approach you should check conditions in if for each goto in each case(cause you can't Go back to each step)

Another approach is to save all cases in the order you want to execute and run the switch multiple times. I use a **while** in my example you can use goto if you don't want to use a loop.

```
Queue<int> cases = new Queue<int>();
//1 is the main switch value
cases.Enqueue(1);
while (cases.Count > 0)
{
int temp = cases.Dequeue();
switch (temp)
{
    case 0:
        Console.WriteLine("0");
        break;
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        cases.Enqueue(3);//run case 3
        cases.Enqueue(0);//then run case 0
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("2");

        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: How does this solve the actual problem of executing two other cases?

Comment: I don't think it helps in case you want to execute 2 branches of switch case at once

Comment: goto doesn't come back, so you can't execute second case.

Comment: @Ralf right you should add checks in each step, I updated my answer with another Approach

Comment: IMHO, much too complicated and hard to read

Comment: About advising to use `goto`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful.

Comment: @wohlstad It should always be avoided, thats why I said the way of the statement should be changed

Answer (score 3):

C# doesn't have such functionality. You have to create other methods which will do actions for cases 3 and 4 and call them from `case 5` branch. I would suggest to create a separate class `FooHandler` which would handle your value. It's easily extendable and readable.

```
public class FooHandler
{
    private readonly int _foo;

    public FooHandler(int foo)
    {
        this._foo = foo;
    }

    public void Handle()
    {
        switch(this._foo) 
        {     
            case 3: this.HandleCase3(); break;          
            case 4: this.HandleCase4(); break;
            case 5: this.HandleCase5(); break;
            default: throw new ArgumentException("Foo value is invalid");
        }
    }
    
    private void HandleCase3()
    {
        // Your code for case 3
    }

    private void HandleCase4()
    {
        // Your code for case 4
    }

    private void HandleCase5()
    {
        this.HandleCase3();
        this.HandleCase4();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var fooHandler = new FooHandler(foo);
fooHandler.Handle();
```

Comment: such a shame it can only be done using functions. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add methods (you didn't explain why),
you can use [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-7.0) local variables holding [`Lambda expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

In the example below you can replace the body of the lambdas with whatever code you have for "something" and "something else".
`Action` also supports passing arguments to the lambda's body if you need them.

```
Action something =      () => { Console.WriteLine("something"); };
Action something_else = () => { Console.WriteLine("something_else"); };

switch (foo)
{
    case 3:
        something();
        break;

    case 4:
        something_else();
        break;

    case 5:
        something();
        something_else();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the switch to two ifs:

```
if (foo == 3 || foo == 5) 
{
    //something
} 
if  (foo == 4 || foo == 5) 
{ 
    //something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use if-statements. Here I also used pattern matching to simplify the tests.

```cs
if (foo is 3 or 5) {
    // something
}
if (foo is 4 or 5) {
    // something else
}
```

So simple and easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the code *being intuitive* is important; hence, I would suggest defining helper variables that **clarify intention**.

While not knowing the meaning of `3`, `4` and `5`, a hypothetical example could be:

```
var awesomeFoos = new[] { 3, 5 };
var popularFoos = new[] { 4, 5 };

var fooIsAwesome = awesomeFoos.Contains(foo);
var fooIsPopular = popularFoos.Contains(foo);

if (fooIsAwesome)
{
    // something (preferably refactored to a separate method)
}

if (fooIsPopular)
{
    // something else (preferably refactored to a separate method)
}
```

, where [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-7.0) is found in the *System.Linq* namespace.

An example fiddle is found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6s7sjC).

---

That being said, though; you seem quite determined that you would prefer to keep your code as-is, to an as large extent as possible. If that is really a high priority, you could consider putting the whole `foo`-`switch` logic inside a method and let it call itself twice in the `case 5` scenario:

```
private static void HandleFoo(int foo)
{
    switch(foo) 
    {     
       case 3:     
       {             
           // something
       }break;          

       case 4:     
       {             
           // something else
       }break;      

       case 5:     
       {             
           HandleFoo(3);
           HandleFoo(4);
       }break;      
    }
}
```

Example fiddle is found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/29O8sy).

(Depending on the content of `// something` and `// something else`, this may not be feasible, though.)

Comment: yeah, first solution is cool, but I have over 20 cases there would be a lot of ifs and it would be kind of messy. And the second is very natural but doesn't work for me for a reason. But thanks for help anyway. Really appreciate